# Application of Intermediate Value Theorem for five-point formula (numerical differentiation)

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have a specific, for-learning-sake-only question on how the author of this link:

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151A/hw5/Hw5_solutions.pdf

gets past the details of the Intermediate Value Theorem on the following paragraph. If someone could fill in the details for me, it would be greatly appreciated because I'm having a hard time understanding.

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{3}{12h}f^{(5)}(\xi_1)+\frac{18}{12h}f^{(5)}(\xi_2)-32\frac{6}{12h}f^{(5)}(\xi_3)+243\frac{1}{12h}f^{(5)}(\xi_4)\right)\frac{h^5}{120}&= \\
\left(\frac{3}{12}f^{(5)}(\xi_1)+\frac{18}{12}f^{(5)}(\xi_2)-32\frac{6}{12}f^{(5)}(\xi_3)+243\frac{1}{12}f^{(5)}(\xi_4)\right)\frac{h^4}{120}&= \\
6f^{(5)}(\xi)\frac{h^4}{120}&= \\
\frac{h^4}{20}f^{(5)}(\xi)
\end{align}$$

"Note that the IVT was used above..."

Shouldn't it be

"Suppose $f^{(5)}$ is continuous on $[x_0-h,x_0+3h]$ with 
$x_0-h < \xi_1<x_0<\xi_2<x_0+h<\xi_3<x_0+2h<\xi_4<x_0+3h.$ Since $\frac{1}{4}[f^{(5)}(\xi_1)+f^{(5)}(\xi_2)+f^{(5)}(\xi_3)+f^{(5)}(\xi_4)]$ is between $f^{(5)}(\xi_1)$ and $f^{(5)}(\xi_4)$, the Intermediate Value Theorem implies that a number $\xi$ exists between $\xi_1$ and $\xi_4$, and hence in $(x_0-h,x_0+3h)$, with $f^{(5)}(\xi)=\frac{1}{4}[f^{(5)}(\xi_1)+f^{(5)}(\xi_2)+f^{(5)}(\xi_3)+f^{(5)}(\xi_4)]$"?

Comment: For other readers: problem 4 in the link.

Comment: If $a,b,c,\cdots$ are non-negative and add up to 1, and interval $I$ contains $x_1,x_2,\cdots$ then by IVT there is some $t$ in $I$ such that  $f(t)=af(x_1)+bf(x_2)+\cdots$, simply because a convex combination is somewhere between the highest and lowest values. But in your example one of the coefficients is negative $-32*6/12$.

Comment: @Maesumi OK. So does that mean this example is flawed?

Comment: Without additional conditions I think it is incorrect. Consider a continuous positive function $y=f(x)$ on $I=[a,b]$. Can we say there is $c$ in $I$ such that $f(c)=2f(a)-f(b)$? No. Just take $f(b)>2f(a)$ and you have a counter-example as you will force $f(c)$ to be negative. But if all coefficients were positive as in $f(c)=0.4 f(a)+0.6 f(b)$ then Yes, because the average with positive coefficients is between the the numbers $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Perhaps the theorem can be corrected by assuming little variation on the quantity that is being averaged, in your case the fifth derivative.